# Extracting all possible keys from a JSON column in Clickhouse

Tags: json, clickhouse

I have a table in Clickhouse that has a `properties` column. This column is a **JSON type column** and stores an object with several keys and values. No arrays, just a single object with multiple keys and values.

What I am trying to do is to build a list of all the unique key names present in the column.

So, if the column has this object:

```
{ age: '25'}
```

And also this object:

```
{ genre: 'pop'}
```

I'd like to retrieve `age` and `genre` as results for this query.

Any way this can be done?

Comment: I have found JSONExtractKeys, if that may hint you in the right direction https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/#jsonextractkeys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up realizing that my use case is better suited for a **MAP** column type.

After changing it to **Map**, doing what I wanted was very easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT arrayJoin(mapKeys(properties)) AS keys
FROM groups
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all of the inferred columns/keys from a ClickHouse JSON column using the DESCRIBE command with the setting  describe_extend_object_types=1;

For example:

```
DESCRIBE TABLE json_test
SETTINGS describe_extend_object_types = 1

Query id: bfa406b0-948c-460f-9e05-6981b5f52270

┌─name──┬─type───────────────────────────┬─default_type─┬─default_expression─┬─comment─┬─codec_expression─┬─ttl_expression─┐
│ key   │ UInt32                         │              │                    │         │                  │                │
│ value │ Tuple(json_key Int8, value String) │              │                    │         │                  │                │
└───────┴────────────────────────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

The value column in the `json_test` table is actually a JSON type, but it currently stores two keys, `json_key` which is an Int8, and `value`, which is a String type.

I believe at the moment you'd have to parse the results of the DESCRIBE TABLE query to use those column names/keys in another query.